# How to get average marginal effects (AMEs) with standard errors of mlogit or clogit in R?

Tags: r, mlogit, marginal-effects, r-marginaleffects

I am fitting a conditional logit model in R and want to compute the average marginal effect of a binary predictor (wait_long: 1 if wait time is >= 30). How should I do it? Any thoughts are welcome (solutions to clogit preferred tho).

```
library(mlogit)
library(survival)

data("TravelMode", package = "AER")

TravelMode <- TravelMode %>%
  mutate(chosen = ifelse(choice == 'no', 0 , 1),
         wait_long = ifelse(wait >= 30, 1, 0))

m_logit <- mlogit(choice ~ wait_long + travel + vcost | 0, TravelMode)
c_logit <- clogit(chosen ~ wait_long + travel + vcost + strata(individual), method = "efron", robust = TRUE, TravelMode)
```

I tried marginaleffects, effects, and predict. But they are either too slow or wrong in my case, esp. for clogit. My real dataset is much larger and therefore speed matters.

I was also checking Stata posts on this issue (clogit and xtlogit with fe) and it seems it is not appropriate to do AME after xtlogit fe (see [this](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1361258-new-on-ssc-aextlogit-average-elasticities-for-fixed-effects-logit) post). aextlogit is instead suggested. But when I run with my data, the coefficients are extremely close to the semi-elasticities. Confused...

Comment: Please state if you only want AME or standard errors as well.

Comment: Hi @jay.sf thanks for your reply. I want both AME and se and no alternative specific betas (that's why I prefer clogit).

Comment: If your dataset is very large, then AME means that you'll be computing estimates for every single row, which can be slow. You might consider creating a smaller dataset with "representative values" of your numeric predictors (ex: the mean) and all observed combinations of your categorical predictors. Then, you can feed this to the `newdata` argument of a `marginaleffects` function, and use the `wts` argument to re-weight the estimates by their prevalence in your original data.